# Django Celery issue with multiple instances

Tags: django, celery

I have two instances of Celery. I want to be able to notify all users of a particular event via email, push, etc. However, I want to make sure that all users get notified only ONCE. Is there an example of how to loop through users and gaurantee each user gets contacted once?

The solution I have is to simply mark the user as having received notification... But that would be very inefficient. And there could be a condition where the user gets notified inbetween the mark is being saved.

I tried to read the following regarding this:

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

**[EDIT]**

By 2 instances I mean 1 worker on two EC2's, so 2 workers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read this one? [Ensuring a task is only executed one at a time](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html#cookbook-task-serial)

Though I think your approach is good, but storing it a database is `slow`, you should cache it to put very quickly. As a simple setup, you could cache the email (hashed) before sending the email. If the cache already exist, then don't send the email.

So it would be something like

```
from hashlib import md5
from django.core.cache import cache
from celery import task

# 1 day because I expect that the whole email task finish within a day
# But the same email may be send out if executed on the next day.
LOCK_TIME = 24 * 60 * 60

@task
def notify_user(email):
    uid = md5(email).hexdigest()

    # This will return False if the uid already exists in the cache
    if cache.add(uid, 'notified', LOCK_TIME):
        send_mail("Subject", "Message", None, [email,])
```

NB: I think Deleting the cache may not necessary. Since you only care to send once till it expired.

Comment: Isn't the cache unreliable?

Comment: You just have to make sure that the server never died. That's probably the trade off from another approach of yours which store the flag into the DB